# python list remove too near numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use a list as matplotlib ticks, but if the ticks too near, it will be overlapped each other.

So it's better to remove too near numbers. for example:

```
distance = 10

x = [1,2,3,20,21,23,30,40,50]

f(x) = [1,20,30,40,50]
```

What's the best way to get such a result?

Comment: How you will define what is too near number?

Comment: if draw tick overlapped, then I will increase the distance manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the list to verify that:

```
x = [1,2,3,20,21,23,30,40,50]
distance = 5
for index in range(len(x)-1 , 0 , -1):
    if (x[index]-distance <= x[index-1] ):
        x.remove(x[index])
print(x)
```

you can change the distance according to your preference, hope that helped

Comment: It`s the best solution I could think of hahaha

Comment: It works fine, I dont think you`ll have problems with speed in this loop

Comment: got it, you remove it from end to beignning. since no need to access it again, so remove is safe.